# How to align text in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Have a look at [my site](http://tourbazaar.co.in/kashmir-tour-package/).

I want to align the text. For example:

```
Day 4              Visit Gulmarg. Around 2 hours drive. Enjoy the majestic view while on
way. Visit the magnificient snow covered hills. Skating can also be done. You can also
take ride in the Rope ways (Gondola) to reach    upper Gulmarg where you can enjoy more
snow clad mountains. Get back to Srinagar and night stay in the hotel.
```

Should be:

```
Day 4              Visit Gulmarg. Around 2 hours drive. Enjoy the majestic view while on
                   way. Visit the magnificient snow covered hills. Skating can also be
                   done. You can also take ride in the Rope ways (Gondola) to reach
                   upper Gulmarg where you can enjoy more snow clad mountains. Get back to
                   Srinagar and night stay in the hotel.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I have tried to enter the spacebar to align but failed

Comment: you have to use the style sheet for this with div or span

Comment: Would probably get better answers on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

By having a look at the code from your site it seems that you have manually given spaces through wordpress wysiwyg editor. Try removing those extra spaces and give a margin or padding through css.